# Javascript searching for text in an array

Tags: javascript, python, json

I'm having problem with searching for a bit of text in a array. I just want to search for some of the text in the array and not all.

my array:

```
var myJSONObject = [
    "2013-01-08: (7:24) vs (7:35)",
    "2013-01-08: (2:15) vs (1:10)",...
```

`document.write(include(myJSONObject, "2013-01-08: (3:4) vs (8:3)") + "<br>");` is true.

`document.write(include(myJSONObject, "(8:3)") + "<br>");` is not.

so, how can I search for just (8:3) and print all that strings that have (8:3) in it.

I do this in python: `[x for x in list if "(8:3)" in x]`

Comment: Iterate over the array values and use indexOf.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.filter (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_filter.htm):

```
 var search = "(8:3)",
     res = Array.filter(myJSONObject, function(in) {
       return in.indexOf(search) > -1;
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
var myJSONObject = [ "2013-01-08: (7:24) vs (7:35)", "2013-01-08: (2:15) vs (1:10)",...
for(var i =0;i<myJSONObject.length;i++){
if(myJSONObject[i].indexOf("8:3")!=-1){
   document.writeln(myJSONObject[i]);
}else
   document.writeln("8:3 not found");
}
```